# When i am starting my Tomcat, instead of opening the welcome file, it is downloading it. Can any one help me out here.?

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2

When ever i am starting my server it is downloading the "login.xhtml". It is inside a pages folder in Webcontent. Path which i have used for welcome file list in web.xml is "/pages/login.xhtml". Moreover this is happening only from eclipse. From browser i am getting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pages folder directly under root (i.e. on the same level as Web-inf folder), which I believe is the case here, then to configure welcome file list you need to give path as pages/login.xhtml.
code:
      pages/login.xhtml

You should not be starting the path with a "/". 404 is a clear indication of this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did changes,but still problem persists. I dont see any new error either.

Comment: are you still getting the 404 on your browser ?

Comment: Yes. I have simply made a web dev project in eclipse.used tomcat 7. did basic jsf config in eclipse. added jsf-impl and jsf-api jars in lib of WEB-INF, changed the port address, since it was giving error as used port. And i am getting error which is even confusing

Comment: can you post the directory structure w.r.t to your root folder?

Comment: and what about other folders like web-inf and html?

Comment: WebProjectJSF--->JavaResources
             --->WebbContent--->META-INF
                            --->pages
                            --->WEB-INF--->lib--->jsf-impl.jar
                                             --->jsf-api.jar

Comment: not sure if i followed  you but pages folder should be directly under WebContent folder.